# how to get the user id from this array and print that

Tags: javascript

i have code to get the my friend list from facebook

the code is................

```
function getFriends() {
    //if the person has not pressed login button
    if(!loggedIn) {
        loginFacebook();
    }

    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Now loading your friends' id...";

    //if the person is loggedIn
    if(loggedIn) {
        document.getElementById("friendBtn").disabled = "disabled";
        FB.api("/me/friends",function(response){
                friends = response["data"];
                totalToBeLoaded = friends.length;
            //  addNewRow("Name","id");
                loadid(friends.length);

        });
    }
}
```

the response["data"] function returns the data in the form of array as

```
{
 "data": [
  {
     "name": "name 1",
     "id": "123456781"
  },
  {
     "name": "name 2",
     "id": "123456782"
  },
  {
     "name": "name 3",
     "id": "123456783"
  },
  {
     "name": "name 4",
     "id": "123456784"
  },
  {
     "name": "name 5",
     "id": "123456785"
  },
  {
     "name": "name 6",
     "id": "123456786"
  }
  ]
}
```

now i need to get that name and id of the user from that response["data"] and print that .. how to do that?

Comment: Please note: this is not an Array, but an *Object* containing a property 'data', which stores an Array of Objects ;~).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its an array of objects. You can use the following:

```
var list=response["data"];
for(var i=0;i<list.length;i++) {
    addUser(list[i].name, list[i].id);
}
```

EDIT:
Even first line can be written as

```
var list=reponse.data;
```

Comment: actually i need to print that. if i use document.writeln only one id is printed....(since it prints in a new page the for loop get running in background) any way to print all id .......

Comment: @learnfromothers: Easy way: document.getElementById("SomeDiv").innerHTML += list[i].name + "<br />";

Comment: @learnfromothers: Cem's answer is something you should always do in Javascript, btw. In general you shouldn't use document.write or document.writeln, as they will break page loads if they're not used within window.onload, and you can only write in-place rather than anywhere in the DOM.